# Toggle class for individual element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Uber noob here, I am trying to create a Javascript/DOM memory game,
The problem I am running into is flipping 1 card versus all of them

Full code is here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PedeYq

```js
$(".card").on("click", flipCard);

function flipCard(event) {
  cardFlip();
}
function cardFlip() {
    HERE.toggleClass('open show')
}
```

However I seem to be trying to toggle this card( see where it says HERE), doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery the event handler function's `this` is the clicked element:

```js
$(".card").on("click", cardFlip);

function cardFlip() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open show');
}
```

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}

.open {
  background: blue;
}

.show {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

Another option is to use `event.target`:

```js
$(".card").on("click", cardFlip);

function cardFlip(event) {
  $(event.target).toggleClass('open show');
}
```

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}

.open {
  background: blue;
}

.show {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: Okay I had tried the event.target before but i was using that incorrectly

`
$(".card").on("click", flipCard);
function flipCard() {
  cardFlip(event);
}
function cardFlip(event) {
    $(event.target).toggleClass('open show')
}
`

Comment: `flipCard() { cardFlip(event); }` doesn't pass event

Answer (score 1):

jQuery sets `this` to the target element in its event handlers. You can pass `this` to `cardFlip`.

```js
$(".card").on("click", flipCard);

function flipCard(event) {
    cardFlip(this);
}
function cardFlip(HERE) {
    HERE.toggleClass('open show')
}
```